# erreur: suggest parentheses around operand of ‘!’ or change ‘&’ to ‘&&’ or ‘!’ to ‘~’

Tags: logical-operators

I'm trying to compile dapl-myrinet-12-0.12 from sourceforge

I got

```
/root/dapl-myrinet-12-0.12/dapl/udapl/../common/dapl_ep_modify.c:584: erreur:
suggest parentheses around operand of ‘!’ or change ‘&’ to ‘&&’ or ‘!’ to ‘~’
```

here is the "problematic" line :

```
if (ep_param->recv_evd_handle != NULL &&
    (DAPL_BAD_HANDLE (ep_param->recv_evd_handle, DAPL_MAGIC_EVD) ||
    ! ((DAPL_EVD *)ep_param->recv_evd_handle)->evd_flags & DAT_EVD_DTO_FLAG))
```

any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error suggest, the code miss a couple of parenthesis around the last part of the condition (the *corrected* condition is exploded here to highlight matching parenthesis) :

```
if (
    ep_param->recv_evd_handle != NULL &&
    (
        DAPL_BAD_HANDLE (ep_param->recv_evd_handle, DAPL_MAGIC_EVD) ||
        !(
            ((DAPL_EVD *)ep_param->recv_evd_handle)->evd_flags & DAT_EVD_DTO_FLAG
         ) 
    )
)
```

You could also disable this check from GCC (if it's the compiler you use), with the `-Wno-parentheses` switch. Anyway, you should report this to the maintainer of the program to let hi fix his code.